# Node.js form validation gives Cannot read property 'profileimage' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to make a form in Node.js using Express by following a tutorial. I am writing the validation logic which should show error messages if the form
gets submitted empty, however instead of doing that it gives me this error on line 33 and I can't figure out why:

```
Cannot read property 'profileimage' of undefined
```

I debugged it but couldn't figure out what is causing this.
What am I doing wrong, how can I fix it?

Here is the form code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

router.get('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('register', {
      'title': 'Register'
  });
});

router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login', {
      'title': 'Log In'
  });
});

router.post('/register', function(req, res, next) {
  var name = req.body.name;
  var email = req.body.email;
  var username = req.body.username;
  var password = req.body.password;
  var password2 =  req.body.password2;


  // Check for Image Field
  if(req.files.profileimage){
      console.log('uploading File...');

      // File Info
      var profileImageOriginalName = req.files.profileimage.originalname;
      var profileImageName = req.files.profileimage.name;

      var profileImageMime = req.files.profileimage.mimetype;
      var profileImagePath = req.files.profileimage.path;
      var profileImageExt = req.files.profileimage.extension;
      var profileImageSize = req.files.profileimage.size;
  } else {
      // Set a Default Image
      var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
  }

    // Form Validation

    req.checkBody('name','Name field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('username','Username field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password','Password field is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2','Password do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    // Check for errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors){
        res.render('register', {
            errors: errors,
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            password2: password2
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            username: username,
            password: password,
            profileImage: profileImageName
        });

            // Create User
            User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
                if(err)throw err;
                console.log(user);
            });

            //Success Message
            req.flash('success', 'You are now registered and may log in');

            res.location('/');
            res.redirect('/');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and my app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.connection;


var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


// Handle file uploads
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: './uploads' });

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Handle Express Sessions
app.use(session({
    secret:'secret',
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true
}));

// passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Validator
app.use(expressValidator({
  errorFormatter: function(param, msg, value) {
      var namespace = param.split('.')
      , root    = namespace.shift()
      , formParam = root;

    while(namespace.length) {
      formParam += '[' + namespace.shift() + ']';
    }
    return {
      param : formParam,
      msg   : msg,
      value : value
    };
  }
}));

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use(flash());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});

app.get('*', function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.user = req.user || null;
    next();
});

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you give us more details regards of which Express middleware you are using right now?

Comment: I updated my question with the app.js file

Comment: Can you confirm that the data coming from your front-end client is using a Content-Type of `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 1):

First of all `files` should be an **array**. If you are sure you send only one file try with this code block:

```
  // Check for Image Field
  if(req.files && req.files[0] && req.files[0].profileimage){
      console.log('uploading File...');

      // File Info
      var profileImageOriginalName = req.files[0].profileimage.originalname;
      var profileImageName = req.files[0].profileimage.name;

      var profileImageMime = req.files[0].profileimage.mimetype;
      var profileImagePath = req.files[0].profileimage.path;
      var profileImageExt = req.files[0].profileimage.extension;
      var profileImageSize = req.files[0].profileimage.size;
  } else {
      // Set a Default Image
      var profileImageName = 'noimage.png';
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the following line in your code:

```js
if(req.files.profileimage){
```

when `files` is undefined, meaning, `req` does not have the property `files` (maybe a file was not sent on this request?), then trying to access anything within it will throw an error (and crash your node if you don't catch it)

So, first you should add type safety like so:

```js
if(req.files && req.files.profileimage) {
```

or, even stricter, like so:

```js
if(typeof req.files === 'object' && req.files.profileimage) {
```

(Note: you should do type safety test if and only if another part of your code has not already guaranteed that it is safe, e.g. a previous type safety test, or you assigned the property explicitly yourself in the code)

I also see that you are using multer to get a files object in your `req` object. Accroding to its docs, `files` can be an array, or an object of strings to arrays, From the "multer" npm page:

If used like so:

```js
app.post('/photos/upload', upload.array('photos', 12), function (req, res, next) {
```

It will be an array:

> req.files is array of `photos` files
>
> req.body will contain the text fields, if there were any

Or, if used like so:

```js
var cpUpload = upload.fields([{ name: 'avatar', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'gallery', maxCount: 8 }])
app.post('/cool-profile', cpUpload, function (req, res, next) {
```

then it will be a (String -> Array) object:

> req.files is an object (String -> Array) where fieldname is the key, and the value is array of files
>
> e.g.
>
> req.files['avatar'][0] -> File
>
> req.files['gallery'] -> Array

So you should change your code accordingly. For example, if you choose the second method, you should change to the following:

```js
if(typeof req.files === 'object' && req.files.profileimage) {
  req.files.profileimage.forEach((profileimage) => {
    //do anything you previously did on req.files.profileimage, on profileimage
    let profileImageMime = profileimage.mimetype;
    //... more things and code...
  })
}
```